# Django + what NOSQL is the most mature for use in production?

Tags: django, mongodb, cassandra, hbase, nosql

I would like to use Django with a NOSQL solution. Are there any production ready NOSQL solutions that work nicely with the latest Django 1.3 ?

Comment: The "comparison" question has been asked and answered a dozen times. Why don't you search first Stackoverflow? Not sure they this should be answered over and over again...do your research homework. A clear -1 for not doing your homework.

Comment: @RestRisiko could you please present a very recent answer on this subject? I did some research on this but the answers I found were outdated. I just wanted to know the NOSQL & Django developments as of today. No hard feelings for the -1. I can take it like a man :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [django non-rel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django). Currently it has support for appengine and mongodb. There are some work done for redis and cassandra too. This project is supposed to be merged with django 1.4 once it´s ready.

Personally I´ve successfully created a simple test app for appengine using it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit weird to say "i want to use a NoSQL". Every NoSQL is different, it's not magic and it doesn't solve every problem.

Comment: I recognize my statement sounds a little bit like "I'll Have What She's Having" in the Meg Ryan movie :) but the reason I asked that way is because I wasn't sure if there is any NOSQL solution that works with Django.  For my project I think Cassandra would be a better choice but I'm not sure if Cassandra and Django are integrated and tested enough to be used in production.

Comment: i don't know cassandra, but i think it's more for storing TB of logs than for "real" web.

Comment: I've read about Cassandra and other NOSQL solutions and it you don't have to wait to have TB of data to implement it. I might use it because it's supposedly faster than MySQL I've been using and for higher availability. I've read that MySQL has in average 300ms/350ms write/read speeds and Cassandra for the same set of data is 0.12ms/15ms write/read speeds. I think it's worth looking into this matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go with [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) you might take a look at [Couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/), which has a [Django extension](http://couchdbkit.org/docs/django-extension.html).

> This extension provides you a
>   threadsafe access and management of
>   documents and views in your django
>   application with some useful tools
>   specific to Django.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain better what you are trying to do with Django or how does your data look like.

We ended up using Django and developed our own custom http-based "service" into Mongo and Neo4j. We manipulated the json data ourselves.